# Where are the capacitors for m.2-SSDs?

Tags: ssd

SSDs have physical block-sizes larger than the report to the operating system. These blocks can be only written as a whole, i.e. not partitially. But the write-requests made by the operating-system are mostly smaller. So to ensure the whole block has to be written non-destructive former SATA-SSDs have large capacitors which help writing a block to the end on power.down; this allows journalling filesystems to stay in integrity. If you look at Google Images and google for "capacitor SSD" you find a lot of pictures of SATA-SSDs and slotted SSDs with their capacitors.

But when you look at a m.2-SSDs there are not such large capcacitors to find. So where are the capacitors for the m.2-SSDs?

Comment: Highly likely in the motherboard circuitry.

Comment: To build on @spikey_richie's comment, capacitors come in all shapes and sizes, so it's likely they're either on the PCB surface and are simply smaller than you're expecting, causing you to miss them, or they're built into one of the PCB layers, depending on how many layers an arbitrary M.2 SSD has.

Comment: In addition to other great comments its possible they simply don't exist - Last I looked - years ago - the inclusion of caps/supercaps was one of the main things differentiating consumer and server class SSDs. Also, m2 is a lot faster, so maybe it can handle the writes with smaller caps, and or use something akin to journalling when moving/writing blocks.

Comment: @davidgo: The slotted PCIe-x16-SSDs are also very fast, nevertheless they have the same large capacitors SATA-SSDs have.